# Find the nearest Value to a giving one without using lambda Please

Tags: python

How can I find the nearest Value **without using a lambda function**? I have found the answer using lambda function but I don't really understand what is happening.

```
def nearest_value(values, one):
    if one in values:
        return one
    else:
        return min(values, key=lambda x: abs(x - one))

print(nearest_value({4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 17}, 9))  # == 10
print(nearest_value({4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 17}, 8))  # == 7
print(nearest_value({4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 17}, 9))  # == 8
print(nearest_value({4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 17}, 9))  # == 9
print(nearest_value({4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 17}, 0))  # == 4
print(nearest_value({4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 17}, 100))  # == 17
print(nearest_value({5, 10, 8, 12, 89, 100}, 7))  # == 8
print(nearest_value({-1, 2, 3}, 0))  # == -1
```

Comment: Did you have an alternative to a `lambda` in mind?

Comment: Did you consider instead of looking for alternatives to try and learn and understand the `lambda`? It is much better to try and **understand** new stuff than to **avoid** them. lambda is a useful tool to master in Python

Answer (score 4):

```
def nearest_value(values, one):

    def not_lambda(x):
        return abs(x-one)

    if one in values:
        return one
    else:
        return min(values, key=not_lambda)
```

Answer (score 1):

A lambda expression is nothing magic, it's just a function. We could just as easily define a normal function:

```
def nearest_value(values, one):
    if one in values:
        return one
    else:
        def absolute_distance(x):
            return abs(x - one)
        return min(values, key=absolute_distance)
```

If you're confused about key functions in general, here's how they work with `min`:

Every value in `values` is given to the key function (`absolute_distance` here, the lambda expression in your original code), and then we take the argument that produced the smallest value when given to this function. In other words, it's equivalent to

[image: arg min of x for absolute_distance(x, one)]

, or the more verbose Python code:

```
def min_absolute_distance(values):
    best_key, best_val = None, None
    for value in values:
        current_key = abs(value - one)
        if best_key is None or current_key < best_key:
            best_key = current_key
            best_val = value
    return best_val
```